# chartJS legend border issue in reactJs

Tags: chart.js, react-chartjs, react-chartjs-2

Hey everyone I am experiencing some issue with the legend of chartjs
Every time i increase the borderWidth property of a dataset it increases the legends borderWidth as well - Current Behavior
But i want to increase the width of the line without increasing the border of the legend - Expected Behavior
Any suggestion would be really helpful TIA[enter image description here][1]

- Current Behavior
  [1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/dVW7A.png